Which books can one read as a Noahide?
What Sefarim is a Noahide allowed to read/learn? Does that change depending on whether or not he plans to do a formal conversion?

I am not aware of any restrictions regarding what books you can read. There are some restrictions for a Jew to teach Torah to a non-Jew (and quite a few questions on the topic here). If you plan to convert, you will need to speak with a rabbi, and he can advise you further on the best books to learn to prepare for this
